# Azure recovery vault backup policy through arm wont change timezone

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, recovery

I'm trying to automate some deployments of azure recovery vault and some policies.

However i can't seem to get it to change the timezone of the policy through ARM.

I've currently tried to hardcode the timezone value to "Romance Standard Time" but it doesn't seems to accept it

```json
"name": "defaultbackupPolicies",
        "count": "[length(parameters('recoveryPolicies'))]",
        "input": {
          "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
          "instantRpRetentionRangeInDays": "5",
          "timeZone": "Romance Standard Time",
```

But it's still defaulting to UTC

Comment: Do you see any errors while deploying the template? Does specifying a different TZ work? Also try including a larger snippet of your template in the question.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: No, i dont see any issues while deploying @BhargaviAnnadevara. The other part of the policy is just the retention period configuration, with a ton of parameter logic

Comment: @JoyWang No i havn't had any progress on the issue, with the exception of getting some colleagues to confirm the issues

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify `"timeZone": "Romance Standard Time"` in `properties` of resource `Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies`.

Try the sample works for me, `testpolicy` is the policy configured with `Romance Standard Time`.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vault_name": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults",
            "apiVersion": "2021-01-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vault_name')]",
            "location": "westus2",
            "tags": {
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "RS0",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2021-01-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vault_name'), '/testpolicy')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults', parameters('vault_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
                "instantRPDetails": {},
                "schedulePolicy": {
                    "schedulePolicyType": "SimpleSchedulePolicy",
                    "scheduleRunFrequency": "Daily",
                    "scheduleRunTimes": [
                        "2021-05-04T04:30:00Z"
                    ],
                    "scheduleWeeklyFrequency": 0
                },
                "retentionPolicy": {
                    "retentionPolicyType": "LongTermRetentionPolicy",
                    "dailySchedule": {
                        "retentionTimes": [
                            "2021-05-04T04:30:00Z"
                        ],
                        "retentionDuration": {
                            "count": 180,
                            "durationType": "Days"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "instantRpRetentionRangeInDays": 2,
                "timeZone": "Romance Standard Time",
                "protectedItemsCount": 0
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

Check the result in the portal:

[image]